# fileupload control in C# for videos

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am designing a website that will upload video files in ASP.NET. The question I have is: video files can get very huge (i.e. 3GB) and I read that increasing the `maxRequestLength` in the webconfig file will give the chance for hackers to attack the server with large requests.

I already know about client validation to protect from malicious files that are not the intended files, so that's not a concern at the moment. My question is if the file-upload method is the right approach to upload video files? If not, is there a better approach?

Comment: Have you considered uploading to a different server?

Comment: Agree! Take a look at this blog post - http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: @DanielA.White What do you mean to a different server? Upload the file to a network server? Wouldn't that be a three way connection trying to retrieve the file from the user to a webserver then transfer to another one? maybe I am not following you

Comment: another web server dedicated to uploading.

Comment: @DanielA.White- could you describe that environment in more detail. Are you saying have the web solution for uploading the videos on a different webserver then the rest of the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For upload big file in asp.net,I used "Brettle.Web.NeatUpload"

You can get it at http://neatupload.codeplex.com/

I hope it is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://www.plupload.com/ combined with chunked uploads inside an ashx handler.  On the server I push the parts to amazons S3, so the server never has the full file in memory. works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to be concerned about this issues is that the built in functionality within the dotNET framework for handling file uploads to IIS in ASP.NET is written to cache the entire file upload to memory before streaming the file out to disk. Hence if you allow very large file uploads, you stand the risk of allowing someone to perform a Denial Of Service style attack on your IIS server because all it takes is a blast of several very large file uploads at once to exhaust available physical memory on the server. Hence the answer to that is to either write your own upload handler that does not cache the entire file upload to memory, or use one of the many available software components that can be installed and do this for you. The other two answers point to a couple. Here's another example component I found for ASP.NET:

http://www.easyalgo.com/eaupload.aspx